# Модификатор static у интерфейса

Tags: java, интерфейс

Копаясь в репозиториях гитхаба нашёл странный код.

У интерфейса который был объявлен внутри класса были модификаторы `public` и `static`.

Ну, `public` вроде как можно и опустить — интерфейс всегда `public`. А что означает `static` у интерфейса? Первый раз такое вижу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модификатор `static` для вложенных интерфейсов избыточен. Вложенные интерфейсы являются `static` [автоматически](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1). Тем не менее, Java позволяет написать `static`, компилятор ошибку не выдаст:

> A member interface is implicitly static. It is permitted for the declaration of a member interface to redundantly specify the static modifier.

Что касается модификатора `public`, здесь вы ошибаетесь, интерфейсу [можно](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1) задать модификатор доступа `private` или `protected`, если он находится внутри класса:

> The access modifiers protected and private pertain only to member interfaces whose declarations are directly enclosed by a class declaration.

Comment: А разве внутренний интерфейс по умолчанию public ? только что проверил и нет, он не public, а такой же как и все другие члены класса по умолчанию

Comment: @VanechikSpace, cпасибо, очень хорошее замечание, я поправил ответ и добавил еще одну ссылку на java-спецификацию.